# How to store react console logs on server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging, client

We want to analyze what issue has been caused on the client side.
How to store client console log on the server side.

How frequently do we need to send the log to the server for storing?
While sending new logs we need to exclude previously sent logs to the server.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

You can import the Console class, also import "fs".

Then, you can :

```
import { Console } from "console";
import fs from "fs";

const logger = new Console({
  stderr: fs.createWriteStream("errorOutput.txt"),
});

logger.error("The error you want to send");
```